# using pyxml library pyjamas

Tags: python, django

I need to write a small web app that does xml parsing on the client browser

I am considering pyjamas as the front end framework and django for the backend.

I understand that with pyjamas one can code in python and javascript is automatically generated

my question is: can I use external python libraries such as pyxml to be used by pyjamas to manipulate xml on the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See 'supported modules' in the Pyjamas docs.